# Disappearance of "Sign in with LinkedIn" button after log-in

Tags: javascript, button, authentication, linkedin-api

My goal is implement a social log-in button for the 3 big (Fb, LinkedIn, Twitter) and use data captured from social (email, first name, last name) to prefill a form inside the landing page.

I have implemented a "Sign in with LinkedIn" Button with the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
  api_key: {my api_key}
      onLoad: onLinkedInLoad
    authorize: true
</script>

   <script type="text/javascript">
function onLinkedInLoad() {
  IN.Event.on(IN, "auth", function() {onLinkedInLogin();});
  IN.Event.on(IN, "logout", function() {onLinkedInLogout();});
}

function onLinkedInLogout() {
  setLoginBadge(false);
}

function onLinkedInLogin() {
  // we pass field selectors as a single parameter (array of strings)
  IN.API.Profile("me")
    .fields("firstName", "lastName", "industry", "location:(name)", "picture-url", "headline", "summary", "num-connections", "public-profile-url", "distance", "positions", "email-address", "educations", "date-of-birth")
    .result(function(result) {
      setLoginBadge(result.values[0]);
    })
    .error(function(err) {
      alert(err);
    });
}

function setLoginBadge(profile) {
  if (!profile) {
    profHTML = "<p>You are not logged in</p>";
  }
  else {
    var pictureUrl = profile.pictureUrl || "http://static02.linkedin.com/scds/common/u/img/icon/icon_no_photo_80x80.png";
  alert( profile.firstName);
  alert( profile.lastName);
   alert(profile.emailAddress);

      $("#field0").val(profile.firstName);
      $("#field1").val(profile.lastName);
      $("#field2").val(profile.emailAddress);
      $("#field3").val(profile.emailAddress);

     profHTML = "<p><a href=\"" + profile.publicProfileUrl + "\">";
    profHTML = profHTML + "<img align=\"baseline\" src=\"" + pictureUrl + "\"></a>";      
    profHTML = profHTML + "&nbsp; Welcome <a href=\"" + profile.publicProfileUrl + "\">";
    profHTML = profHTML + profile.firstName + " " + profile.lastName + "</a>! <a href=\"#\" onclick=\"IN.User.logout(); return false;\">logout</a></p>";
  }
  document.getElementById("loginbadge").innerHTML = profHTML;
}
</script>

    //LinkedIn Button


<script type="IN/Login">


  <input type="hidden" id="fnameLinkedIn" name="linkedin-id" value="<?js= firstName ?>" />
  <input type="hidden" id="lnameLinkedIn" name="linkedin-id" value="<?js= lastName ?>" />

  </script>
```

The code works but the "Sign in with LinkedIn" Button disappears when I logged in with LinkedIN.
I would mantain the LinkedIn button after the login.

How can I avoid the disappearance of LinkedIn button?

Thank You for the support.

Alex

Comment: How did you solve the problem ?

Answer (score -1):

You're using the JS API, in which the sign-in button automatically disappears after being logged in. This is how the API works, and that's how it should work.

Using the JS API, the user is automatically signed in to your site as long as they are signed in into linkedin.com . If the user is signed in, you can grab any data and used it in your forms immediately.

Comment: Ok but if I do login with Facebook  I would show newly the "Sign In with LinkedIn" button (doing Log out from LinkedIn)

Comment: If the user is logged in on your website, you should hide all of them, that should solve your problem

Comment: Same problem here. Do you have some advance on this? (I do agree that login button should disappear on login BUT it should be placed after logout)